C and CXX compiler identification is unknown
I am trying to cross compile the sdk in am62x evm device for ota but it is not happening!(Not in local machine)
root@am62xx-evm:~/zoho-iot-sdk-c-master/output# cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
 
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
 
 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
 
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
 
 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/root/zoho-iot-sdk-c-master/output/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/root/zoho-iot-sdk-c-master/output/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

gcc and g++ both package are included and the image is our customised image have used.
If anyone has a solution, please share it, it will be of great help.

If you have C and C++ compilers installed, then you could try to specify path to them in CC and CXX environment variables, as the error message tells you. Alternatively you may specify those parameters in cmake parameters -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=<..> and -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<..>.

Note, that cross-compilation with CMake implies a toolchain file. The project you are building notes about that: see section "Porting/Cross Compile Options" in their README.
